# What is difference between _googleSignIn.signOut and _googleSignIn.disconnect in Flutter GoogleSignIn?

Tags: flutter, google-signin

What is right usage or better way of under the two methods?

**Method one**

```
Future<bool> signout()async{
  try {
    await _googleSignIn.disconnect();
    await _googleSignIn.signOut();
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
```

}

**Method two**

```
Future<bool> signout()async{
  try {
    await _googleSignIn.signOut();
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
```

}

Flutter Package [Google_Sign_In](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difference between signout and disconnect is explain here :-
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/disconnect

As my perspective this was better I use google signing my 8 apps and all are live on both stores I use this method everywhere

```
Future<bool> signout()async{
  try {
    await _googleSignIn.signOut();
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. which time should we use the disconnect method?

Comment: disconnect method allow user to disconnect their Google account from your app For more info visit https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/disconnect